# Проблема в отображении statusBar поверх Toolbar

Tags: android

Панель инструментов находится поверх Toolbar. Как это исправить?

[image: Панель инструментов находится поверх Toolbar.]

Вот разметка

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonFrame" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:src="@drawable/sa_edit_schedule"
                    android:background="@drawable/schedule_btn"
                    android:padding="@dimen/sa_margin_edit_img" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonCloseFrame"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonFrame" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonClose"
                    android:src="@drawable/sa_close_edit_schedule"
                    android:background="@drawable/schedule_btn"
                    android:padding="@dimen/sa_margin_edit_img" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonCreateFrame" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonCreate"
                    android:src="@drawable/sa_favorite_create"
                    android:background="@drawable/schedule_btn"
                    android:padding="@dimen/sa_margin_edit_img" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonDeleteFrame"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonFrame" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonDelete"
                    android:src="@drawable/sa_favorite_delete"
                    android:background="@drawable/schedule_btn"
                    android:padding="@dimen/sa_margin_edit_img" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Разметку покажите

Comment: Вот разметка моя:

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `android:fitSystemWindows="true"` для `AppBarLayout`

Comment: Это не помогло мнею

Comment: Попробуйте кроме `AppBarLayout` ещё и `CoordinatorLayout` добавить `android:fitSystemWindows="true"`

Answer (score 1):

Не могу понять, что тебе надо исправить. Отступить сверху надо?
Попробуй.

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

в android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout вставить.

Comment: Не, оно без этого делается, надо с `android:fitSystemWindows="true"` поиграться

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для `AppBarLayout` и `CoordinatorLayout` добавить `android:fitSystemWindows="true"`

**UPD_0:**

Также надо чтобы тема вашего приложения наследовала `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. Т.е. в файле `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
<style name="Base.Theme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
</style>
</resources>
```

И в манифесте эта тема должна быть указана:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ru.kuchanov.material" >

<application
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.Light" >
</application>

</manifest>
```

Также проверьте назначаете ли вы в коде `Toolbar` `ActionBar`-ом методом активити `setActionBar(toolbar)`

**P.S.** Всё упомянутое в ответе нужно использовать одновременно. Вот пример приложения, использующего все эти штуки: [тык](https://github.com/mohaxspb/MaterialTemplate)

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не получилось. Какие еще есть варианты? Будут ли видны изменения при просмотре макета внутри AndroidStudio?

Comment: @VladLynnik, смотрите обновлённый ответ. И изменения лучше смотреть на устройстве (или эмуляторе), т.к. хз как просмотр макета работает со всеми этими новыми штуками от гугла.